# Using Java-Insipired Language in Android App

Tags: java, android, javac, bytecode, dalvik

Here is my situation.
I am using a custom programming language thats syntax is based on Java.
In order to compile this *.custom file I use the java classpath to locate the .jar that contains the .class files. This converts the .custom to .java from there I compile down to Java Byte Code and run on JVM. Now I am looking to use this custom language on Android.  Is there a way that I can incorporate a .custom file into android and compile into .java and then to Dalvik Byte Code to run?  Looking for any suggestions to run .custom on Android
Thanks

Comment: The Android dev tools are ultimately operating on Java `.class` files. If you can compile your code into something that will run on the JVM with the class-library restrictions of Android, you can compile the `.class` into a `.dex`. Keep in mind that you'll need to be referring to the Android API in your programs so the Android installer can link them to the Android runtime.

Comment: @Chrylis that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Android dev tools are ultimately operating on Java `.class` files. If you can compile your code into something that will run on the JVM with the class-library restrictions of Android, you can compile the `.class` into a `.dex`. Keep in mind that you'll need to be referring to the Android API in your programs so the Android installer can link them to the Android runtime.

Comment: So if I compile into the class files and then convert to dex and run on Android it should ideally work? My question is how would I initiate the main() in the class file from the onCreate?

Comment: You would have to use the same lifecycle as anything else in Android; you use the manifest and Android entry points, not CLI Java `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either compile to `.class` and then convert that to `.dex` using the `dx` tool. Or you can use [DexMaker](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) to go right to `.dex` from source.

Comment: Ok, i was able to successfully convert a "HelloWorld" function from .custom to dex.  Now how do i go about loading the dex file in a android app?

Comment: Search for `DexClassLoader`.